# There is error on Python Documentation

Tags: windows, python-3.x

When I open python documentation, i see strange words :
'16.3. time � Time access and conversions','What뭩 New in Python' 
like this.

(뭩 is korean word that means nothing. I'm korean student.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDrKe.png)
Why are these happening?
Help me to fix this error.

Comment: "When I open python documentation" - what kind of documentation do you open? Is there a URL for it? Please be specific.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot or url so that we can refer to?

Comment: I assume you're a talking an encoding problem in the compiled HTML docs (CHM). "time — Time access and conversions" contains an EM dash (U+2014). This is defined as 0x97 in codepage 1252. I cracked open python364.chm to look at the header of "library/time.html". It's a Windows-1252  encoded file, but the header contains `charset=cp1252`. Probably the CHM viewer doesn't recognize this, so it defaults to your system locale's ANSI codepage. See [issue 32174](https://bugs.python.org/issue32174).

Comment: Similarly in "What’s New in Python", there's a right single quote (U+2019), which is 0x92 in codepage 1252. If I decode this and the following "s" as codepage 949 (Hangul) -- e.g. `b"\x92s".decode('949')`, then I get "뭩" (U+BB69).

Comment: I add screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows:

I have seen this happen with my Chinese Windows set up. This would resolve if you change your Windows set up to English. This seems to be some sort of font error. Once you set your primary language to English, this should resolve. If not, reinstall python after setting language to English.